# Rebuild array to add keys from a second array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I use Array1 and Array2 to get the Wanted Result?

Array1

```
array(
    (int) 0 => '37',
    (int) 1 => '38'
)
```

Array2

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'ParentKey' => array(
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'ParentKey' => array(
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

Wanted Result

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'ParentKey' => array(
            'Array1Key' => 37,
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'ParentKey' => array(
            'Array1Key' => 37,
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '1'
        )
    )
    (int) 2 => array(
        'ParentKey' => array(
            'Array1Key' => 38,
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'ParentKey' => array(
            'Array1Key' => 38,
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

I have tried several things but this got me the closest...

PHP

```
$data = array();
foreach($Array1 as $id)
{
    foreach($Array2 as $Array1Result)
    {
        $data[]['ParentKey'] = array(
            'Array1Key' => $id,
            $Array1Result['ParentKey']
        );
    }
}
```

Result

```
array(
  (int) 0 => array(
    'ParentKey' => array(
        'Array1Key' => '37',
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '2'
        )
    )
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
    'ParentKey' => array(
        'Array1Key' => '37',
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '1'
        )
    )
  ),
  (int) 2 => array(
    'ParentKey' => array(
        'Array1Key' => '38',
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '2'
        )
    )
  ),
  (int) 3 => array(
    'ParentKey' => array(
        'Array1Key' => '38',
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ChildKey1' => '1',
            'ChildKey2' => '1'
        )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: and the question is...

Comment: Replace `array('Array1Key' => $id, $Array1Result['ParentKey'])` with `array_merge(array('Array1Key' => $id), $Array1Result['ParentKey'])`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois That pretty much did it. Thanks! I just had to take out the `array()` after `$data[]['ParentKey'] =`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Why comment and not answer?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sorry, haven't gotten to it until now :)

Answer (score 2):

What you get is exactly what you do. You put an array inside an array. But you need to merge two arrays together. The first one being the `Array1Key` and the second one the old array. You can achieve this with [`array_merge`](https://secure.php.net/array_merge).

```
$data = array();
foreach($Array1 as $id)
{
    foreach($Array2 as $Array1Result)
    {
        $data[]['ParentKey'] = array_merge(
            array('Array1Key' => $id),
            $Array1Result['ParentKey']
        );
    }
}
```